# How can I organize large number of action-validation.xml files in Struts 2?

Tags: struts2

In a Struts-2 Application, there are many Action classes and action-validation.xml files
for each Action classes how can I organize all these validation xml files into a single
folder such as in a "properties folder" and access validation rules from there.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of it depends on what build system you are using. If you are using Maven to build, for example, you can place the validation.xml files in an identically named package inside of src/main/resources instead of src/main/java. In Ant, you could probably set it up anywhere and have Ant copy the xml files to the correct place in the final war file, though I am not sure how, not really having used Ant much.

I think the key thing is that in the final packaged war, the xml files need to be in the same place as the class files for that action. Where they are before build time doesn't so much matter.

Comment: Thanks Dustin

I am using maven as build tool and put the action-validation.xml in resources folder in the same package hierarchy as in the src folder and the validation is successful.